# Magento 2 - Extending Magento UI /lib/variables/typgraphy.less

Tags: theme, css, extend, variables

I'm looking at `/lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less`

I was able to add a new `@font-family__oswald` to my own `_theme.less`.

Now, I'm trying to edit the h1 tags to make it all uppercase but I can't seem to get it to work. I've placed it in my `_theme.less` and I also tried creating a `_variables_extend.less` and import it into my `_extend.less` file like the Magento documentation.

This is what I've added:

```
@heading__text-transform__base: uppercase;
@h1__text-transform: @heading__text-transform__base;
```

I've also deleted the var folder and `pub/static/frontend` folder. Cleared cache as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own font to your **_theme.less** in **app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/web/css/source/_theme.less**

e.g by adding

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Racing Sans One';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: 
        local('Racing Sans One'), 
        local('RacingSansOne-Regular'), 
        url(http://really-long-url.woff) format('woff');}
```

then apply this font to the elements you want and add the `text-transform`-attribute
e.g.

```
h1 {font-family:'Racing Sans One';text-transform: uppercase;}
```

in **_theme.less** (or any less file you import)

Then depending on the mode you run magento in (developer/production) you might need run `magento setup:static-content:deploy`in order to make this taking affect.

I think this should do it (unless you use other styles that override yours..)

Comment: Yeah that worked if I just did h1{text-transform:uppercase;}.

I was hoping to keep it consistent with doing it the less way.